# In comparison with or when comparing?

Tags: grammaticality, phrases

Please let me know either ***When comparing*** or ***In comparison with*** should be used for cases like the following:

> 1) *When comparing* the existing methods that deal with segmentation using space based point assignment methods (Wenki, 2012), the presented method in this paper has increased the accuracy.
>
> 2) *In comparison with* existing methods that deal with segmentation using space     based point assignment methods (Wenki, 2012), the presented method in this paper has increased the accuracy.

Comment: In both sample sentences, the prepositional phrases that you asked about are dangling, and the sentences don't quite make sense

Comment: @jwpat7: so what it would be sir?

Comment: Niro, see answer instead of this comment.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Either phrase can be used if used appropriately.  However, in both sample sentences the phrases don't properly connect to the latter halves of their sentences.  For the first, a simple change is adding *one finds that* after the comma.  More revision is needed for the second.  Although I don't know what wording you should use, I've shown some alternatives below, with  “segmentation using space based point assignment methods (Wenki, 2012)” replaced by *X* for brevity.  You could ask your question at [writers.stackexchange](https://writers.stackexchange.com/questions).  Ask for help with brevity, clarity, directness.

> • The method presented in this paper exhibits improved accuracy relative to existing methods that deal with *X*.
>   • By comparison with existing methods that deal with *X*, this method has increased accuracy.
>   • Wenki (2012) surveyed existing methods that deal with *X*.  The method presented in this paper is more accurate than those methods.